# How to retrieve the creation date of an AD user from .NET?

Tags: .net, active-directory

I'd like to retrieve the creation date of users in Active Directory. I understand that users have a WhenCreated property, but I cannot see that property exposed on the *UserPrincipal* type I am working with.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Guid, guid);
//var createdDate = principal.CreationDate;
```

Edit: this is a web application running within IIS, querying an AD server on another machine on the same network.

Comment: Is this a desktop or browser application?

Comment: @Keith - its an asp.net mvc web app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to get the underlying DirectoryEntry (part of the `System.DirectoryServices`-namespace).

You can use this extension method to get the date as a string:

```
public static String GetProperty(this Principal principal, String property)
{
    DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
    if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(property))
        return directoryEntry.Properties[property].Value.ToString();
    else
        return String.Empty;
}
```

Use like this:

```
var createdDate = principal.GetProperty("whenCreated");
```